# Issue in clearing local storage in wizard form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the step wizard forms and the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    localStorage.removeItem('dateFormat');
    readcategories();
    ...
    ...
    });

function getDateFormatFromDatabase() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?action=getDateFormat',
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data)
        {
            dateFormat = data.dateFormat;
            localStorage['dateFormat'] = dateFormat;
        }
    });
}

function getDateFormat() {
    getDateFormatFromDatabase();
    var dateFormat = localStorage['dateFormat'];
    //  alert(dateFormat);
    return dateFormat;
}

function checkValidDate(dateValue) {
    var dateFormat = getDateFormat();
    ...
    ...
}


..... wizard form code
.....

onFinishing: function (event, currentIndex) {
    var form = $(this);

    var purchasedate = $("#purchasedate").val().trim();
    var purchasedate = new Date(purchasedate);
    if(checkValidDate(purchasedate.toDateString()) == false)
    {
        displayDateErrorMessage("Purchase Date");
        return false;
    }
    ...
}
```

I am clearing the `localStorage` on `document.ready` function because I want it to always contain the new value which is fetched from database in the function `getDateFormat`. Now it is always clearing the `dateFormat`, with the result it always get undefined value and date does not validated...

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIRST:**

Instead of using:

```
localStorage['dateFormat'] = dateFormat;
```

and

```
var dateFormat = localStorage['dateFormat'];
```

You need:

```
localStorage.setItem('dateFormat', dateFormat);
```

and

```
var dateFormat = localStorage.getItem('dateFormat');
```

Read more about localStorage [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).

---

**SECOND:**

The function `getDateFormatFromDatabase();` contains an ajax call. As ajax call is an asynchronous operation, it means you will not get the `dateFormat` set to `localStorage` after calling `getDateFormatFromDatabase();`. To fix that, you need make it synchronous by setting `async: false`:

```
function getDateFormatFromDatabase(callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?action=getDateFormat',
        type: 'POST',
        async: false,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function(data)
        {
            localStorage.setItem('dateFormat', data.dateFormat);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It always returned as null value and also if i remove the line  localStorage.removeItem('dateFormat'); it works accordingly

Comment: Should i keep localStorage.removeItem('dateFormat'); or not on ready function

Comment: You can remove it.

Comment: it is throwing Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user’s experience in console